# Who is reviewing Flags

Tags: support, flags

Is there any way to find the name of the flag reviewer?

You only get a status (disputed, declined or helpful) currently.

Comment: Go [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/283712/get-all-review-tasks-for-a-specific-post-id) and enter the post id. Only works for stuff older than a week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not. Flags are handled by the moderators or the community as a team.

Moderators mark flags as helpful or declined. If a flag is marked *disputed* then the flag was handled by the community in a review queue and no consensus was reached on the flag.

Comment: do we (10k+) review flag anymore ?  but where there is no option anymore  in tools for flags

Comment: The flag review from the 10k+ tools is long gone. See [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092)

Comment: 10k flag queue was the privilege makes difference between 3k user and 10k user now everything is same and tools has nothing interesting

Comment: So seeing deleted posts, casting delete and undelete votes, tracking what gets delete / close / reopen / undelete voted, and inline tag editing are all uninteresting? I miss all of those very much on sites where I don't yet have 10k.

Comment: those are useful and good but nothing is like flag queue ,imo  :) (i am just missing flag queue so much) nothing against current system

Comment: Why are moderators hiding behind a "community"? I tried to get in touch with "a moderator" who declined my flag, and had to [bother a lot more moderators by posting a question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297197/request-to-review-declined-flag).

Comment: @DanDascalescu: no one is hiding. Take into account we get *thousands of flags per day*, your flag is not the only one we need to process. I handled 823 flags and counting today, for example. Sometimes moderators don't agree with your flag, it happens. It could be that you read the post wrong, it could be that the flag was handled in a review queue, it could be that a moderator got the flag wrong. You perhaps didn't provide enough context. Etc. There is little point in getting upset over one flag however.