# Request to review declined flag

Tags: support, declined-flags

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback/10763818#10763818) as a comment because it talks about the exact code in the accepted answer, but doesn't offer a solution.

[My flag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1269037) was declined based on alleged lack of evidence:

[image]

Since I can't get in touch with "a moderator", I'm posting in here in hope the decision is re-evaluated. The evidence is that the code in the answer is the same as the code in the accepted answer, and the answer comments on a problem with that code.

Comment: Shog's comments from another question may be applicable here too: [Moderator declined flag “Link-only answer”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297157)

Comment: That flag was declined *in April*. Why bring this up only now?

Comment: I was just going through my flag history today.

Comment: My question resulted in the situation being rectified (thanks @bluefeet), yet it has 9 downvotes. *puzzled*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your flag was "Comment, not an answer", I read the answer and it looked like an answer, so I declined the flag.

While you included in your question that it was a comment on the accepted answer, you failed to include that in the flag when asking us to review it.  Had you included anything that stated, "this is a comment on the accepted answer", then I would have been able to compare the two answers and processed the flag. It's important that all details needed to accurately process a flag be included.

Failing to include it, will lead to declines.

Since you've added those critical details in the question, the answer has been deleted by a moderator.